# looping through each element of a string and handling wildcard cases in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, for-loop, substring, wildcard

I want to find if `string1` is substring of `string2`.
e.g. `string1="abc"`, `string2="afcabcdfg"`.

I want to add Wildcard cases, e.g. `"*"` can substitute `"a"` and `"c"`, `"y"` can substitute `"f"` or `"d"`. As a result, `"*by"` should be substring of `"afcabcdfg"`.

What is general way to code it? How should I loop it?

Comment: BTW, you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24670457/edit) your question to add more or updated information, instead of opening a [new question about the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677290/python-looping-through-string-and-matching-it-with-with-wildcard-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

For the example provided by you try using a dictionary to define all the replacements then loop over the characters of the string like this:

```
string2="afcabcdfg"
table = {'a': '*', 'c': '*', 'f': 'y', 'd': 'y'}
new_string = ''

for c in string2:
    if c in table and table[c] not in new_string: new_string += table[c]
    elif c not in table: new_string += c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use re, and a little string manipulation to make yourself a regex.

```
import re
string1 = 'abc'
string2 = 'zbcdef'
wildcards = 'a'

# . is wildcard in a regex.
my_regex = string1.replace(wildcards, '.')

# If there is a match, re returns an object. We don't care
# about what info the object holds, just that it returns.
if re.match(my_regex, string2):
    print "Success"

# If there's no match, None is returned.
if not re.match(my_regex, string3):
    print "Also success"
```