# Python looping through string and matching it with with wildcard pattern

Tags: python, string, loops, python-2.7, wildcard

```
string1="abc"
string2="abdabcdfg"
```

I want to find if string1 is substring of string2. However, there are wildcard characters like `"."` can be any letter, `y` can be `"a"` or `"d"`, `x` can be `"b"` or `"c"`.
as a result, `".yx"` will be substring of `string2`.

How can I code it using only one loop? I want to loop through string2 and make comparisons at each index. i tried dictionary but I wand to use loop
my code:

```
def wildcard(string,substring):
    sum=""
    table={'A': '.', 'C': '.', 'G': '.', 'T': '.','A': 'x', 'T': 'x', 'C': 'y', 'G': 'y'}
    for c in strand:
        if (c in table) and table[c] not in sum:
            sum+=table[c]
        elif c not in table:
            sum+=c
    if sum==substring:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print wildcard("TTAGTTA","xyT.")#should be true
```

Comment: You should use dictionary _and_ loop. In the dictionary, store what characters can be matched by each symbol, and in the loop use that to check each character.

Comment: Alternatively, translate your pattern into a regex, e.g. `.+#` -> `[a-z][bc][ad]`, and then match that regex. I think this is much better, but it does not use a loop.

Comment: Could you please post the code you already wrote and describe what is wrong with it?

Comment: You can not add multiple instances of the same key into a dictionary. If You do `{'A': '.', ..., 'A': 'x'}`, then `A` maps only to `x` or to `.`, not to both. You could use `'A': '.x'` or `'A': ['x','.']` instead; see my answer below (although I do the mapping the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

I know you are specifically asking for a solution using a loop. However, I would suppose a different approach: You can easily translate your pattern to a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html). This is a similar language for string patterns, just much more powerful. You can then use the `re` module to check whether that regular expression (and thus your substring pattern) can be found in the string.

```
def to_regex(pattern, table):
    # join substitutions from table, using c itself as default
    return ''.join(table.get(c, c) for c in pattern)

import re
symbols = {'.': '[a-z]', '#': '[ad]', '+': '[bc]'}
print re.findall(to_regex('.+#', symbols), 'abdabcdfg')
```

If you prefer a more "hands-on" solution, you can use this, using loops.

```
def find_matches(pattern, table, string):
    for i in range(len(string) - len(pattern) + 1):
        # for each possible starting position, check the pattern
        for j, c in enumerate(pattern):
            if string[i+j] not in table.get(c, c):
                break # character does not match
        else:
            # loop completed without triggering the break
            yield string[i : i + len(pattern)]

symbols = {'.': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '#': 'ad', '+': 'bc'}
print list(find_matches('.+#', symbols, 'abdabcdfg'))
```

Output in both cases is `['abd', 'bcd']`, i.e. it can be found two times, using these substitutions.

Comment: From you now-added code it seems you are trying to match genetic codes, so this seems not to be homework but rather practical. Particularly in this case I would strongly recommend my first solution, as this should have much better performance.