# Emulate Python str.find(substring) using iteration but not built-in functions

Tags: python, string, find, substring

How can I find the position of a substring in a string without using `str.find()` in Python? How should I loop it?

```
def find substring(string,substring):
     for i in xrange(len(string)):
        if string[i]==substring[0]:
          print i
        else: print false
```

For example, when `string = "ATACGTG"` and `substring = "ACGT"`, it should return `2`.  I want to understand how `str.find()` works

Comment: How does my solution work for you?

Comment: index is basically the same thing as find. i want to solve the problem without using any built-in functions.my idea is: if substring is in the string, then find i where string[i]=substring[0] and return i. i am not familiar with python

Comment: You're using built-in functions xrange and len, do you mean no string methods?

Comment: Building your own `find` function will inevitably be much slower as many of Python's built-in functions are optimized for speed and/or written in C. What is the reason for making your own function? It looks like you're searching through genome data where speed may be vital.

Comment: See this question for details on how `find` actually works in Python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681649/how-is-string-find-implemented-in-cpython

Comment: The second part of [my answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24677730/1639625) already included such as `find` function (for an exact match, just pass an empty `table`); didn't this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer_moore) or [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt). Both create tables to precalculate faster moves on each miss. The B-M page has a python implementation. And both pages refer to other string-searching algorithms.

Comment: The answers in this other question suggest that the Python `find` implementation is based on Boyer-Moore - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681649/how-is-string-find-implemented-in-cpython

Comment: Yeah, I am sure it is. I am not sure what you are getting at, though. Is this *not* a good answer because it replicates in python the underlying implementation in C? If you had to implement `string.find` from scratch in python, what would you do?

Comment: It seems like a highly relevant answer to me, that's why I upvoted. I was just providing more information - sorry if it sounded critical.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't think of a way to do it without any built-in functions at all.

I can:

```
def find_substring(string, substring):

    def starts_with(string, substring):
        while True:
            if substring == '':
                return True

            if string == '' or string[0] != substring[0]:
                return False

            string, substring = string[1:], substring[1:]

    n = 0

    while string != '' and substring != '':

        if starts_with(string, substring):
            return n

        string = string[1:]

        n += 1

    return -1

print(find_substring('ATACGTG', 'ACGT'))
```

I.e. avoiding built-ins `len()`, `range()`, etc.  By not using built-in `len()` we lose some efficiency in that we could have finished sooner.  The OP specified iteration, which the above uses, but the recursive variant is a bit more compact:

```
def find_substring(string, substring, n=0):

    def starts_with(string, substring):
        if substring == '':
            return True

        if string == '' or string[0] != substring[0]:
            return False

        return starts_with(string[1:], substring[1:])

    if string == '' or substring == '':
        return -1

    if starts_with(string, substring):
        return n

    return find_substring(string[1:], substring, n + 1)

print(find_substring('ATACGTG', 'ACGT'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the constraint of not using `find`, you can use `str.index` instead, which returns a ValueError if the substring is not found:

```
def find_substring(a_string, substring):
    try:
        print(a_string.index(substring))
    except ValueError:
        print('Not Found')
```

and usage:

```
>>> find_substring('foo bar baz', 'bar')
4
>>> find_substring('foo bar baz', 'quux')
Not Found
```

If you must loop, you can do this, which slides along the string, and with a matching first character then checks to see if the rest of the string startswith the substring, which is a match:

```
def find_substring(a_string, substring):
    for i, c in enumerate(a_string):
        if c == substring[0] and a_string[i:].startswith(substring):
            print(i)
            return
    else: 
        print(False)
```

To do it with no string methods:

```
def find_substring(a_string, substring):
    for i in range(len(a_string)):
        if a_string[i] == substring[0] and a_string[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
            print(i)
            return
    else: 
        print(False)
```

I can't think of a way to do it without any built-in functions at all.

Comment: index is basically the same thing as find.  i want to sove the proble without using any buil-in functions

Comment: @Nur How's this, no index?